# How to get ContentType of sitecollection in sharepoint 2013 programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, content-type

How can I get the content type of the site collection in a subsite programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get a list of the content types in the site collection from a subsite.

You can do this by getting a handle to the root web and listing it's content types:

```
SPContentTypeCollection contentTypes;
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web; 
if (web.IsRootWeb)
{
    contentTypes = web.ContentTypes;
}
else
{
    contentTypes = web.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference content types from the site collection from a sub web, just use the following code:

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
var contentTypes = web.AvailableContentTypes;
```

The magic property is "AvailableContentTypes", which also returns site content types:

> To add a site content type to a list programmatically, choose a
>   content type from the collection that is returned by the
>   AvailableContentTypes property of an SPWeb object (server) or a Web
>   object (client). Then add the content type to the list’s collection by
>   accessing the ContentTypes property of the list object and calling the
>   Add method of the collection object. For more information, see How to:
>   Add a Content Type to a SharePoint List.

[Site and List Content Types (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms463016(v=office.14).aspx)